# Get link or path of attached file of post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have post where I upload a file. I want to make a downloadable link. So I use `<?php echo get_attachment_link(); ?>`. But I can't get full path of file.

There is my code

```
<?php
 $reports = array(
 'post_type' => 'post' , 
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'category_name' => 'reports'); 
                              
    $q_reports = new WP_Query($reports);
                    
        if($q_reports->have_posts()){
        while($q_reports->have_posts()){ 
        $q_reports->the_post();?> 

<li><a href="<?php echo get_attachment_link(); ?>" ><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
Published: <?php the_date(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wp_get_attachment_url()` to get full path of file.

Check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_url` needs attachment id, but I don't know how to get that. I have only one file attached in a post. Can you plz help me to get that from above code? I am new and noob in WP.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Link-only answers are discouraged because links can break or change over time. To make your answer more useful to the OP, please edit it to include the important information from the link and an explanation of how they can use this to solve their problem.

Comment: @NirdoshShrestha This function will take default global $post if you don't provide ID.